How to copy/paste Roslyn SyntaxNode?
I'm doing some home project. How can I copy arbitrary SyntaxNode and insert it immediately after original?
Tried this generic method (to cover all cases):
        private void AppendReplaced(SyntaxNode node)
        {
            var parent = node.Parent;
            var replaced = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(_replacer.Replace(node.ToFullString())).GetRoot();
            parent.InsertNodesAfter(node, new[] { replaced });
        }

This fails with error:

Unable to cast object of type
'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.CompilationUnitSyntax' to type
'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.UsingDirectiveSyntax'.

Obviously, there is some internal checks which prohibits invalid syntax (because, well, using can have different meaning in different context and all those kind of problems).
So how one can correctly Clone() node OR disable validation whatsoever? I really need just copy/paste functionality with some minor textual changes and don't really care about correctness/integrity with code base.
PS:
Came up only with this solution:
        private void AppendReplaced(SyntaxNode node)
        {
            ToInsert.Add(Tuple.Create(node.FullSpan.End, _replacer.Replace(node.ToFullString())));
        }

        var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        outputBuilder.Append(input);
        foreach (var t in walker.ToInsert.AsEnumerable().Reverse())
        {
            outputBuilder.Insert(t.Item1, t.Item2);
        }

        output = outputBuilder.ToString();

